# Getting deadlock in SQL Server and deadlock XML showing only victim process

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

We are getting frequently deadlock on update statement and deadlock XML showing only single process(victim Process),so not able to identify the reason behind this.

Also if anyone knows about the meaning of `waitresource="OBJECT: 2:-1195020174:1 "` from the deadlock XML screen shot please let me know.

The error always occurs at the same place. The client is a .NET application running a stored procedures in synchronously. Also this stored procedure executes in 100 ms and it's for insert and update records.We have used transaction in stored procedure.

Has anyone seen anything like this before or know what is going on? Please advice.

[Deadlock XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGcv.png)

Comment: Deadlocks are an extremely complex subject, and there is no one size fits all solution. I highly recommend googling some quality articles on deadlocks and learn how to read the deadlock graph. Its very valuable knowledge, but takes some time to learn,

Comment: Regarding the meaning of the wait resource, it's a tempdb object with a schema modification lock being held. Are you using global temp tables (`##` prefix) in the proc?